# How to display weather data based on the browser location in cq5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jakarta-ee, aem

I need to display the weather information based on my location. Is there any API to do the same?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best Weather APIs free for commercial use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363052/best-weather-apis-free-for-commercial-use)

Answer (score 0):

there is a good post how to use the geolocation from the clientcontext here http://blogs.adobe.com/livecycle/2011/10/bringing-geo-location-to-web-experience-management.html

that might give you a good start